# Retrieve string value inside hover over, from applet

Tags: java, html, hyperlink, applet

I am running an applet in IE which is generated from an external VLX file.

The VLX file is pulling data from a database and when a user hover overs a specific icon when the applet is running, a hover over table appears, with four strings inside, more specifically one of the strings is a URL.

When viewing source it is not possible to see these string values, as they are generated by the VLX and then used by the applet, so the only code you can see is the applet code.

Is it possible to retrieve these strings? As I want to be able to use the URL to open a new web page.

I have it so when a user double clicks the specific icon, an alert is present to show where I am on the page, and within this event I need to use URL value.

This is not possible with the `document.getElementById` as these values are not accessible in the `html`.

Comment: *"..VLX file"*  What is a VLX file?

Comment: A VLX file is just a template that gets converted into XML, I am using an IBM product that generates this and then parse it myself.